# Share a variable between two files?

Tags: python

What is a mechanism in Python by which I can do the following:

file1.py:

```
def getStatus():
    print status
```

file2.py:

```
status = 5
getStatus() # 5
status = 1
getStatus() # 1
```

The function and the variable are in two different files and I'd like to avoid the use of a global.

Comment: The code seems to already work exactly as you've described as is. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: You could try putting the variable into a module and import the module.

Comment: Can you put this in a class ?  import the class in your other file.

Comment: This is kind of weasel-worded. You want to avoid the use of a global but you want some kind of state that persists across files in the form of a variable? **That's what global is.** In order to avoid global state, you need to refactor it into a class, save it in a database, etc.

Comment: This is exactly why you want to avoid global, by the way. You wouldn't want something happening in another file (action at a distance) to change the state your program depends on. That would be very difficult to reason about and therefore to debug.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist globals are not the only mechanism in Python for sharing things between two files.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's not what I said. But there's a big difference between "sharing things between two files" and "I change a variable in file A and file B sees the change without me doing anything different."

Comment: Can somebody reopen this question so I can leave a proper answer? I mistakenly closed it and reopened it earlier, so now I can't reopen it again by myself.

Comment: if `status` is in `file_1.py`, then import file_1 into the `get_status()` file, and print `file_1.status`

Comment: Very true that this isn't a duplicate of "How do I pass a variable by reference?"... but it certainly feels like a duplicate of *something*. Surely someone has asked this before. At the very least, if this is to be reopened, it should be rehabilitated into a better-quality question, starting with a title that better reflects what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share variables without making them global by putting them in a module. Anybody who imports the module gets the *same* module object, so its contents are shared; changes made at one location show up in all the others.

notglobal.py:

```
status = 0
```

get.py:

```
import notglobal

def getStatus():
    return notglobal.status
```

Testing:

```
>>> import notglobal
>>> import get
>>> notglobal.status = 5
>>> get.getStatus()
5
>>> notglobal.status = 1
>>> get.getStatus()
1
```